# Spring Integration upload with dynamic FTP properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-integration

I'm having a web project where I'm using Spring Integration for file upload on remote directory via FTP. However, FTP properties are being loaded dynamically (from database) and they can be different for each request. Naive approach:

Initially create `DefaultFtpSessionFactory` bean:

```
@Bean
public DefaultFtpSessionFactory defaultFtpSessionFactory() {
    return new DefaultFtpSessionFactory();
}
```

`IntegrationFlow` bean:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow integrationFlow(DefaultFtpSessionFactory defaultFtpSessionFactory) {
    // Flow config
}
```

Inject this bean into the controller and set properties:

```
@Autowired
private DefaultFtpSessionFactory defaultFtpSessionFactory;

@Autowired
private FtpConfigService ftpConfigService;

@RequestMapping(value = "upload", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public RequestEntity<String> upload() {
    defaultFtpSessionFactory.setHost(ftpConfigService.getHost());
    // Set other properties
    // ... and upload file

   return new RequestEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Of course, this is a bad idea since there's a race condition (two requests can access `DefaultFtpSessionFactory` singleton in the same time). So, how can I achieve this in a safe manner?

Comment: What you can do is to create a Message that contains your ftp payload and the session properties that you can use to update your sessionFactory in the flow.

Answer (score 1):

Register the final part of the flow dynamically - see [the blog introducing the feature](https://spring.io/blog/2016/09/27/java-dsl-for-spring-integration-1-2-release-candidate-1-is-available); perhaps keep those flows in a cache.

See the [dynamic-tcp-client](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/advanced/dynamic-tcp-client) for an example where we create multiple tcp client adapters dynamically and cache the input channels; use a similar technique for ftp - there's also an older sample for [dynamic-ftp](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/advanced/dynamic-ftp) which pre-dates the DSL and the dynamic flow registration.

Comment: I took a look at your dynamic FTP example since I'm using Spring 4. As far as I see, for each new `MessageChannel` you are creating a new `ApplicationContext` and cache it. Is it possible to avoid creation of contexts? Plus, in order to make everything work, no beans should be autowired on application startup. Which makes things very inconvenient, since configuration classes/XML's must remain out of `@ComponentScan` scope.

Comment: The dynamic flow method (used in the tcp sample I cited) does not create child contexts. You can also use the [Delegating Session Factory](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ftp.html#ftp-dsf) where the actual connection/sesion is determined from a `ThreadLocal`.